# ¿Cuál es correcta, "bases de datos médicas", "bases de datos médicos" o "bases médicas de datos"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico, adjetivos, informática

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de decirlo?

1. bases de datos médicas.
2. bases de datos médicos.
3. bases médicas de datos.

Refiriéndome a las bases de datos que tienen almacenados en sus ordenadores los servicios de salud pública y hospitales.

1. médicas está en femenino porque se referiría a las bases, o al par *bases de datos* que también es femenino.
2. *médicos* en masculino porque se refiere a los datos.
3. sería como *1.* pero poniendo el adjetivo en un lugar que queda más claro, pero me suena raro y si lo googleas sólo obtienes cuatro resultados.

Comment: Así como respuesta rápida yo pondría la 2, porque en realidad lo que es "médico" son los datos, no las bases de datos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vamos a cambiar el adjetivo.

Supongamos que quieres hablar de las bases de datos que tiene la Administración a disposición del público en general. ¿Dirías "bases de datos públicos" o "**bases de datos públicas**"? Yo particularmente escogería la segunda, ya que de lo que estamos hablando es de las bases de datos y de su accesibilidad, no del tipo de dato en sí. Con seguridad, la Administración tiene cientos de bases de datos privadas que almacenan datos públicos; pero no nos referimos a ellas.

De igual manera, los servicios de salud tienen bases de datos médicos, pero también bases de datos no médicos (turnos, facturas a los seguros, registros de las revisiones de los ascensores, lo que sea); si entendemos "médica" como "relativo a los servicios de salud", entonces todas son bases de datos médicas, aunque solo las primeras son bases de datos médicos.

Con eso en mente y dependiendo de si te refieres a las bases de datos médicos exclusivamente, o a todas las bases de datos usadas por los servicios de salud, aplicaría el femenino o el masculino.

Comment: Eso pienso yo también. Además "las bases de datos" es femenino y médicas califica a ese conjunto de palabras.

Answer (score 2):

> Refiriéndome a las bases de datos que tienen almacenados en sus
>   ordenadores los servicios de salud pública y hospitales.

La respuesta correcta es la primera: **bases de datos médicas**. La palabra compuesta *base de datos* es un sustantivo ***femenino***. Es cierto que la palabra *datos* es un sustantivo masculino, pero la pregunta aclara que hablamos de un **tipo** de bases de datos en particular a saber: aquellas que manejan y administran los servicios de salud públicos y hospitales. Aunque contiene *datos médic**os***, la base de datos es médica, del mismo modo en el que, por ejemplo, una base de datos **científica** contiene *datos científic**os***, pero el tipo o clasificación de la base de datos es *científi**ca***.

Con respecto a los pocos resultados que puede tener la búsqueda *bases de datos médicas* en Google puede deberse a que es habitual llamar a ese tipo de bases de datos con otros nombres, por ejemplo: bases de datos de ciencias de la salud, bases de datos de hospitales, bases de datos de salud pública o incluso simplemente historias clínicas. Si el tipo de información que tiene esa base de datos no es lo que interesa sino el dueño de esa información (servicios de salud pública y hospitales) simplemente se les denomina bases de datos de centros médicos.

Comment: @walen toda la razón, error no intencional. Corredigo.